# .gitlab-ci.yml file not able to perform ssh-add

Tags: ssh, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ssh-keys

I am not able to figure out how to solve this problem. please take a look.
`$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 11
$ ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
Enter passphrase for /dev/fd/63: ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`
I am very confused about this and not able to figure out what to do next. Can anyone help me with this?
I am trying to use the following link to run my yml file: https://gitlab.com/memosa/meteor-gitlab-ci/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Seems to be a bug explained here [#14434](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14434)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your private key password protected ? It would explain why it can't be added without providing passphrase. If so, use decrypted private key in your variable.